# Как связать две таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Как связать две таблицы по одному `id_main`, если для одной из таблиц он является `PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT`. Т. е. делаем `INSERT`, а полю `id_main` даем значение `NULL`. Теперь как этот же самый `id_main` записать во вторую таблицу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id_main`) SELECT `id_main` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `id_main` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: Конструктивно.

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id_main) SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: Объясните, а что будет, если между первым **Вашим** insert (в table1, правильно ?) и этим (в table2) **другой** пользователь базы введет данные (скажем в table1)? 

Просто я не знаком с тонкостями MySQL, поэтому не могу понять, как работает LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: Я тоже не большой знаток MySQL, но подозреваю, что LAST_INSERT_ID вернет последний автоинкремент внутри сеанса. Куда интереснее вопрос - что она вернет, если оператор INSERT выполняет вставку в еще какую то таблицу с автоинкрементом (триггер может это сделать). Желающие могут поэкспериментировать
MS SQL, который мне куда ближе, может различить такие штуки,  используя SCOPE_IDENTITY и @@IDENTITY